# Only last row in method execute (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4.3

First I want to apologize for my lack of knowledge in programming in general. I am in the way of learning and have discovered that this site is a huge compliment for me of doing so.

I have created a program with three UITextField(thePlace,theVerb,theOutput) and two UITextView where one of the textviews(theOutput) take the text from the other textview(theTemplate) and replaces some strings with the text entered in the textfields.

When I click a button it triggers the method createStory that is listed below. This works fine with one exception. The text in the output only changes the string 'number' to the text in the textfield. However if I change the order in the method to replace 'place','number','verb' only the verb is changed, not the number.

Im sure this is some sort of easy fix but I can't find it. Can some of you help me with my troubleshooting?

```
- (IBAction)createStory:(id)sender {
    theOutput.text=[theTemplate.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<place>" withString:thePlace.text];
    theOutput.text=[theTemplate.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<verb>" withString:theVerb.text];
    theOutput.text=[theTemplate.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<number>" withString:theNumber.text];
}
```

Many thanks
// Emil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're overwriting the contents of `theOutput.text` with each line; `var1 = var2;` overwrites the data in `var1` and replaces it with the contents of `var2`.

Try this:

```
- (IBAction)createStory:(id)sender 
{
   NSString* tempStr = [theTemplate.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<place>" withString:thePlace.text];
   tempStr = [tempStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<verb>" withString:theVerb.text];
   theOutput.text = [tempStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<number>" withString:theNumber.text];
}
```

Does this make sense? :)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. However after a night sleep I figured out an even smarter way of writing it. Instead of changing the output from the template every time, I change the output from template the first time, the second time i change the output from the first output, and the third output from the second output.

Comment: theOutput.text = [theTemplate.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<place>" withString:thePlace.text];
    theOutput.text = [theOutput.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<verb>" withString:theVerb.text];
    theOutput.text = [theOutput.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<number>" withString:theNumber.text];

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)createStory:(id)sender {
    theOutput.text=[theTemplate.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<place>" withString:thePlace.text];
    theTemplate.text=[theTemplate.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<verb>" withString:theVerb.text];
    theTemplate.text=[theTemplate.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<number>" withString:theNumber.text];
}
```

does this work?

Comment: That doesn't work. The last two lines changes `theTemplate.text`, which doesn't affect `theOutput.text` which is presumably what's desired.

Comment: wups. that's not what I meant to do at all :P

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that `thePlace.text` and `theVerb.text` are not returning empty values? But this is not your issue.

```
NSLog(@"thePlace: %@",thePlace.text);
NSLog(@"theVerb: %@",theVerb.text);
```

Your code should be:

```
- (IBAction)createStory:(id)sender {

    NSString * output = theTemplate.text;

    output = [output stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<place>" withString:thePlace.text];
    output = [output stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<verb>" withString:theVerb.text];
    output = [output stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<number>" withString:theNumber.text];

    theOutput.text = output;
}
```

Comment: You neglected to assign `output` to `theOutput.text`.

Comment: That also worked, however I found an easier solution described in one of the comments above. Thanks for your time!